# cef class SimpleHandler has no member

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

what am I doing wrong extending the **cefsimple** app, getting the same error with either of functions:

**#1** *class "SimpleHandler" has no member "OnContextCreated"*

simple_handler.h

```
#include "include/cef_render_process_handler.h"
class SimpleHandler : /*...*/ public CefRenderProcessHandler
// ...
virtual CefRefPtr<CefRenderProcessHandler> GetRenderProcessHandler() {
return this; }
virtual void OnContextCreated(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser, 
CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame, CefRefPtr<CefV8Context> context) OVERRIDE;
```

simple_handler.cc

```
void SimpleHandler::OnContextCreated(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser, 
CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame, CefRefPtr<CefV8Context> context) { /*do stuff*/ }
```

**#2** *class "SimpleHandler" has no member "OnBeforeBrowse"*

simple_handler.h

```
class SimpleHandler : /*...*/ public CefRequestHandler
// ...
virtual CefRefPtr<CefRequestHandler> GetRequestHandler() OVERRIDE { return 
this; }
virtual bool OnBeforeBrowse(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser, 
CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame, CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request, bool is_redirect) OVERRIDE
```

simple_handler.cc

```
bool SimpleHandler::OnBeforeBrowse(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser, CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame, CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request, bool is_redirect) { /*do stuff*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled everything to the newest version and it worked, for reference if anyone comes across the same problem.

simple_handler.h

```
class SimpleHandler :  /* ... */ public CefRequestHandler {
  /* ... */
  virtual CefRefPtr<CefRequestHandler> GetRequestHandler() OVERRIDE { return this; }
  // CefRequestHandler methods:
  bool OnBeforeBrowse(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                      CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
                      CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
                      bool is_redirect) OVERRIDE;
}
```

simple_handler.cc

```
bool SimpleHandler::OnBeforeBrowse(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                   CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
                                   CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
                                   bool is_redirect) {
                                   CEF_REQUIRE_UI_THREAD();

return true; // disable links
}
```